# Model inheritance – use 'where' depending on attribute

Tags: inheritance, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-models

I have a user model and a dealer and customer model, which inherit the user class and have no own database table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Dealer < User
  before_save :set_default_values

  def set_default_values
    self.role_id = Role.find_by_handle('dealer').id
  end
end

class Customer < User
    …
end
```

I don´t use scopes because i want something like a dealer_path and some custom logic per role.

Now i´m wondering how to tell my dealer/customer model that it´s role-dependent, so that i can use (for example) Customer.all and just get users with the role 'customer'.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just apply default scopes to your new classes?

```
class Dealer < User
  default_scope { where(:role_id) = Role.find_by_handle('dealer').id }
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails' built-in [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) feature. Just add a column called 'type' to User, and set the value to 'dealer', 'customer', etc.

Comment: Hmm yes, but i have a role model and storing the role of a user as role_id. So i would need something like STI with role_id:integer instead of type:string.